# Alamofire 2, how to get NSError?

Tags: swift, swift2, alamofire

In alamofire 2 they introduced result types:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
    .responseJSON { request, response, result in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
        case .Failure(let data, let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

**error** is of type **ErrorType** and its only member is **debugDescription** which prints:

> Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "Es besteht
>   anscheinend keine Verbindung zum Internet."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x135f4e7c0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=myurl,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=myurl,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=Es besteht anscheinend keine Verbindung zum
>   Internet.})

How can I get just the NSLocalizedDescription from the error and not the whole debug message?

In alamofire 1 the error was of type NSError and could get the error message with:

```
error.localizedDescription
```

however this seems to be not possible in alamofire 2. Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSError/localizedDescription

Comment: @MartinR the only member of error is "debugDescription" which is a string.

Comment: You are right, I misread the question and assumed that `error` is an `NSError`. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the ["Alamofire 2.0 Migration Guide"](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%202.0%20Migration%20Guide.md) it is stated that a new result type

```
public enum Result<Value> {
    case Success(Value)
    case Failure(NSData?, ErrorType)
}
```

was introduced and that Alamofire still only generates NSError objects.

In ["Why and how any ErrorType can always be casted to NSError?"](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17431) a member of the
Apple Stuff confirmed that an `ErrorType` can always be cast
to an `NSError`:

> ... The reason this works is because of "compiler magic." The compiler
>   automatically emits the code necessary to translate between any
>   ErrorType and NSError.

So this compiles and printed the expected result in a quick
test (e.g. "Could not connect to the server."):

```
switch result {
case .Success(let JSON):
    print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
case .Failure(let data, let error):
    print((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine now. A little correction to your answer. The compiler wants me to use "error as! NSError" instead of just "error as NSError".

Comment: @artworkadシ: Which Xcode version did you use? I am using the final Xcode 7.0 (7A220), and a forced cast  `error as! NSError` gives the compiler warning *"forced cast from 'ErrorType' to 'NSError' always succeeds; did you mean to use 'as'?"*.

Comment: My bad, your answer is correct. However if I access error like this: result.error I have to use as!

Comment: @artworkadシ: Yes, because the `error` property of `Result` returns an optional: `ErrorType?`.

Answer (score 2):

The ErrorType can be converted to an NSError. Try this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
    .responseJSON { request, response, result in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
        case .Failure(let data, let error):
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a String on the error object:

```
error.localizedDescription
```

Comment: nope, "Value of type ErrorType? has no member 'localizedDescription'